# Trying to push a value using a dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, push

I'm trying to write a function that pushes an item onto the end of my dynamically allocated array (not allowed to use vectors). Once it goes to the area to double the size of the list if the list was too small to store the next number, it all goes to hell and starts feeding me back random numbers from the computer. Can anyone see why it's not doubling like it's suuposed to?

```
    int *contents_;
    int *temp;
    int size_ = 0;
    int capacity_ = 1;


    void pushBack(int item) /**appends the specified value to DynArray; if the contents array is full,
    double the size of the contents array and then append the value **/
    {
        if (size_ == capacity_)
        {
            capacity_ = (2*capacity_);
            temp = new int[capacity_];
            for (int i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
            {
                temp[i] = contents_[i];
            }
            delete [] contents_;
            contents_ = temp;
        }
        contents_[size_++] = item;

    }
```

EDIT **** I forgot to mention. This is a function out of a class. This is in the header and in main :

```
 main()
{
DynArray myArray;
myArray.pushBack(2);
myArray.pushBack(3);

myArray.printArray();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize and use this?

Comment: I don't think an array counts as a list if this is a homework assignment.

Answer (score 4):

If this is your initial setup:

```
int *contents_; // Junk
int size_ = 0;
int capacity_ = 1;
```

Then your code is most likely performing a memory access violation upon the first time it does:

```
if (size_ == capacity_)
{
     // Not entering here, contents_ remains junk
}
contents_[size_++] = item;
```

Answer (score 0):

As barak implied, the contents_ pointer needs to be initialized. If not, c++ will point it to something you probably don't want it to.